# iOS 15.2.1 Safari - PWA - An internal error was encountered in the Indexed Database server

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

Every day my iOS users get this error in Safari (IOS 15.2.1). It's a standalone PWA builded with Angular 13, using localForage for writing to Safari IndexedDB

```
Uncaught (in promise): UnknownError: An internal error was encountered in the Indexed Database server
```

Subsequent:

```
Uncaught (in promise): UnknownError: Connection to Indexed Database server lost. Refresh the page to try again
```

Has to reload the page everytime to get it back :(

I cannot find any pattern in it, can even reproduce it my self, it just happens all of a sudden... I cannot use localstorage instead because is limited to 5MB per app per browser.

Does anyone know this error? Maybe have a workaround for it?

I really hope it gets fixed in iOS 15.3 along with known security hole in IndexedDB...

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue with ReactJS. 

"UnknownError: Connection to Indexed Database server lost. Refresh the page to try again"

What I've noticed is that it seems to occur when the user returns to an active(already open) session after a long period of time. For example, on SentryIO the last transaction was at 21:19, and the Error occurs at 00:53. I've also had some users where the time between the last transaction and the error were 10+ hours apart.

Are you by chance using Firebase? We're using Firebase Auth and I think the issue is related to the SDK but not entirely sure.

Comment: I do not use Firebase. I'm pretty sure it's a bug iOS Safari. My users also reported that it is after some time when they are out of the app and come back in later. Im not 100% sure, but it seems that this error "Attempt to iterate a cursor that does not exist" now comes instead of "An internal error was encountered in the Indexed Database server" after updating to iOS 15.3! I try to catch the error and fix it without reloading the whole page... I have status in a few days...

Comment: My users still get this error "Connection to Indexed Database server lost. Refresh the page to try again" in iOS 15.3

Comment: @Mike Exact same thing here... i have semi-ignored it for now (using Ionic here). Haven't heard much back from users, but i guess they just reload the app, if "something is off". Curious if you ever solved the issue?